# Modifying anchor tag class from none to active using selenium & python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to modify the class of an anchor tag from none to "active". This is the html:

```
<li class="item-1">
  <a href="#" class="active">
  </a>
</li>
<li class="item-1">
  <a href="#" class="">
  </a>
</li>
```

How can i change the class of the first

element to nothing and the class of the second

element to "active" using selenium in Python?

I am looking for the following:

```
<li class="item-1">
  <a href="#" class="">
  </a>
</li>
<li class="item-1">
  <a href="#" class="active">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Try webdriver.execute_script(). This will let you execute synchronus JS code within your python code.  The best ways to change a class is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/8669719